What short film features a woman kneading dough until she becomes enveloped in it?
I'm looking for a short film that features a young woman kneading a large blob of dough. It's quite tough and sticky, and the kneading apparently takes a lot of effort, so there are lots of shots of her sweating, the dough sticking to her arms and clothes, etc. Eventually it evolves into a sort of fight/lovemaking with the dough, while the woman removes bits of clothing due to the apparent physical effort of this kneading.
I'm not completely sure, but I think the woman was in various states of undress, possibly ending up completely naked during her doughy struggle.
If I remember correctly, the woman eventually is enveloped fully by the dough, and the movie ends. 
This was in color, live action. I would presume I saw it on television somewhere between 2000 and 2010, and judging from the quality I'd say it was filmed somewhere in that period as well, or somewhere early to mid-nineties at the earliest. As I remember it, the woman had dark hair, worn up, and an apron (at first). It was unspoken, so it could basically have come from any country. It "felt" French, somehow, but for all I know it was American, British, German, or whatever.
Anyone know what this is?

I'm assuming this was live action and not animated?

Yes, sorry, I'll add it to the question.
